# How to display first 3 number and last 3 numbers in ngFor loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi here i have a list of numbers like

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

so here using *ngFor i am displaying like below

```
<div *ngFor =" let data of array">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
```

so here i dont want to display all the numbers instead i want to show on 1,2,3 .... 8,9,10(including dots)

here i followed this technique but for first 3 number and dots how can i do that ? say i need to display first 3 numbers and last 3 number irrespective of numbers

```
<li *ngFor="let project of (projects | slice:projects.length - 4);">
```

**Note: I cannot do the changes in the .ts code as i am getting data as nested array so i need in template .html level**

Comment: why don't you slice the array in the .Ts before sending it to the html !

Comment: You could do `(projects | slice:projects:0:2)`. As suggested by @AlyAbdElRahman, it would make sense to do the slicing ahead of time and include additional checks that the array is long enough, there are no overlapping items, a conditional to check whether you need to display the dots, etc.

Comment: i cannot as it is a deep nested array

Comment: @ExplosionPills the data which i am getting a deep nested array so i cannot slice it

Comment: @phan686 in that case, you may need to update or write a new question that reflects the true nature of the data you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

a quick way would be doing this

```
<div *ngFor =" let data of array; let i = index">
    <p *ngIf="i< 3 || i > array.length - 4 ">{{data}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: How can i set dot inbetween the first three and last three numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by creating a custom pipe that includes your logic.

```
import {Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'arrayfilter',
    pure: true
})

export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(itemsArray: any, args?:any): any {
        if(itemsArray.length > 1) {
           return itemsArray.filter((_,i,{length}) =>  
           (i < 3 || i + 3 >= length));
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML file looks like below

```
<div *ngFor =" let data of sample_array | arrayfilter">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array and prevent duplicate items for smaller arrays.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (const value of array.filter((_, i, { length }) => i < 3 || i + 3 >= length)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: But this i cannot do it in template level right using ng For

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr *ngFor="let dc of (drdInfo.companyList['data'] | slice:drdInfo.companyList['data'].length - 4)">
```

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let dc of (drdInfo.companyList['data'] | slice:drdInfo.companyList['data'].length - 4)">

Comment: Hi, please add some explaination to your answer

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let dc of (array | array.length - 4)"> </tr>